# C: Punteros operadores & y *

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código

```
int main(void){

    char saludo [10]="Amigo";
    char* puntero = &saludo;
    printf("Nuestro puntero apunta a: %p \n",puntero);
    printf("La variable saludo esta en: %p \n",&saludo);
    if(&saludo == puntero){
        printf("Las direcciones apuntan al mismo lugar: %p \n",puntero);
    }
    *puntero = "Hola";//Modifico a donde apunta mi puntero
    printf("%s",saludo);
    return 0;

}
```

El problema que tengo es que después de compilar, lo que veo en consola no es lo que espero:

```
Nuestro puntero apunta a: 0xbfb47942 
La variable saludo esta en: 0xbfb47942 
Las direcciones apuntan al mismo lugar: 0xbfb47942 
�migo
```

Cuando lo que en realidad espero es una salida del tipo:

```
Nuestro puntero apunta a: 0xbfb47942 
La variable saludo esta en: 0xbfb47942 
Las direcciones apuntan al mismo lugar: 0xbfb47942 
Hola
```

Comment: Tu error de concepto es que una asignación como `a="cadena"` no copia esa cadena al "interior" de la variable `a`. Eso lo haría `strcpy(a, "cadena")`. Lo que hace en cambio es guardar el texto `"cadena"` en una dirección arbitrariad e memoria (en la zona de las cadenas estáticas o literales) y _asignar a `a` la dirección en que ha sido guardada. En tu caso estás cambiando el primer carácter de "Amigo" por el primer byte de esa dirección. Si hicieras en cambio `p="Hola"`, funcionaría bien, pero estarías cambiando la dirección a que apunta `p`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parece que no tienes del todo claro cómo funcionan los operadores unarios<sup>1</sup> `*` (des-referencia) y `&` (dirección de).

#### Contexto.

El operador de "*des-referencia*" o "*contenido-de*" sólo puede ser usado con punteros (o al declarar punteros) y obtiene el contenido de lo que sea que apunta el puntero:

```
int valor = 42;
int* puntero = &valor;
int** puntero_a_puntero = &puntero;
int*** puntero_a_puntero_a_puntero = &puntero_a_puntero;

printf("%d", ***puntero_a_puntero_a_puntero); // Muestra 42
printf("%d", *valor); // Error 'valor' no es un puntero
```

En el ejemplo anterior, tenemos una variable que es un puntero triple (apunta (1) a un puntero que apunta (2) a un puntero que apunta (3) a un valor), por eso si queremos el valor debemos des-referenciar tres veces.

El operador de "*dirección de*" se puede usar con cualquier variable y obtiene un puntero al tipo de la variable:

```
int valor = 42;
int* puntero = &valor;
int** puntero_a_puntero = &puntero;
int*** puntero_a_puntero_a_puntero = &puntero_a_puntero;
```

En el ejemplo anterior, la "*dirección de `valor`*" obtiene un puntero a entero (`int*`) porque `valor` es entero (`int`); mientras que la "*dirección de `puntero`*" obtiene un puntero a puntero a entero (`int**`) porque `puntero` es puntero a entero (`int*`) etc…

#### Problemas.

Una vez aclarado cómo funcionan los operadores unarios `*` y `&`, veamos qué uso les has dado en tu código y por qué el uso es incorrecto.

En estas declaraciones de variables:

```
char saludo [10]="Amigo";
char* puntero = &saludo;
```

El tipo de `saludo` es `char[10]` (formación<sup>2</sup> de diez caracteres), el nombre de una formación es un puntero al primer elemento de la misma, por lo tanto: sabiendo que `saludo` es una formación de caracteres (`char`) el nombre de la formación es un puntero a carácter (`char*`).

Si obtenemos la dirección de la formación con el operador dirección-de, sabiendo que el nombre de la formación es un puntero a carácter (`char*`) el resultado será puntero a puntero a carácter (`char**`), ¡pero lo estás guardando en una variable de tipo puntero a carácter!

Sigamos:

```
*puntero = "Hola";
```

Sabemos que `puntero` es un puntero a carácter (`char*`) por lo que al des-referenciarlo obtenemos un carácter (`char`), este carácter será el primer elemento de la formación<sup>2</sup> a la que apunta `puntero`.

Asignas al primer carácter de la formación a la que apunta `puntero` el literal de texto `"Hola"` que es de tipo `char[5]`, y que es interpretado como puntero a carácter (`char*`); es decir: en un carácter (`char`) guardas un puntero a carácter (`char*`).

Los punteros se guardan en variables de 32 o 64 bits<sup>3</sup> pero los caracteres son de 8 o 16 bits<sup>3</sup> así que se trunca parte del valor del puntero para guardar lo que se pueda, lo cuál da lugar a un carácter no imprimible (`�`) cuando muestras la variable por pantalla.

#### Propuesta.

Si usases bien los operadores unarios `*` y `&` tu código debería parecerse a lo que ha mostrado [SuperG280](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/290067/2742):

```
int main(void)
{
    char saludo [10]="Amigo";
    char* puntero = saludo; // SIN operador dirección-de

    printf("Nuestro puntero apunta a: %p \n",puntero);
    printf("La variable saludo esta en: %p \n",saludo);

    if(saludo == puntero) // SIN operador dirección-de
    {
        printf("Las direcciones apuntan al mismo lugar: %p \n",puntero);
    }

    puntero = "Hola"; // SIN operador de des-referencia
    printf("%s",saludo);
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>El asterisco `*` se puede usar como operador de multiplicación (`int i = 3 * 2;`) o como operador de des-referencia (`int v = *x;`) el primero es el uso binario y el segundo es el uso unario. El [et](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) `&` se puede usar como operador de AND binario (`int i = 7 & 3;`) o como operador de dirección de (`int *p = &x;`) el primero es el uso binario y el segundo es el uso unario.

<sup>2</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

<sup>3</sup>Dependiendo de la arquitectura del sistema u otros factores.

Answer (score 5):

Tienes varios problemas en este programa. Para empezar, tienes que pensar que el nombre de la variable definida como

```
char saludo[10] = "Amigo";
```

es la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del array. La variable `saludo` ya es una dirección de memoria, por eso cuando te quieres referir al contenido y no a la dirección de memoria, haces cosas como saludo[i], donde i es la posición dentro del array que quieres consultar, empezando en cero.

Dicho esto, si quieres un puntero al array, lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
char * puntero = saludo;
```

y no

```
char * puntero = &saludo;
```

es más, esto último en mi compilador ni siquiera compila. Tienes que quitar todos los & que has puesto delante de la variable saludo.

Así que tu programa quedaría así:

```
int main(void){
    char saludo [10]="Amigo";
    char* puntero = saludo;
    printf("Nuestro puntero apunta a: %p \n",puntero);
    printf("La variable saludo esta en: %p \n",saludo);
    if(saludo == puntero){
        printf("Las direcciones apuntan al mismo lugar: %p \n",puntero);
    }
    puntero = "Hola";//Modifico a donde apunta mi puntero
    printf("%s",saludo);
    return 0;
}
```

Pero esto no da el resultado que tú quieres. Cuando haces:

```
puntero = "Hola";
```

estás haciendo que puntero apunte a otro sitio, pero no alternas en nada la variable `saludo`, que sigue apuntando a la cadena `"Amigo"`, así que cuando haces el último `printf`, obviamente te imprime el contenido de `saludo`: `"Amigo"` y no `"Hola"` como tu querías.

Comment: El código del OP, compilar ... **compila**. Cierta cantidad de *warnings*, pero compila: https://wandbox.org/permlink/EyGvOUticMZUpsuw

Comment: Con Microsoft Visual Studio esa línea no compila y da un error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char (*__w64 )[10]' to 'char *'

Comment: El código mostrado por el OP es perfectamente compilable, siempre y cuando el compilador use cadenas literales `utf-8`. Como ya habrás observado por el mensaje de error que indicas, tu compilador no lo hace.

Comment: Efectivamente, las cosas de Microsoft son como son... Y los estándares se los pasa por donde se los pasa...