# No reconoce la variable en c

Tags: c, funciones, matriz

estoy realizando un programa que me pida varios datos, uno de ellos es con cuantas empresas quiero trabajar, entonces el usuario introduce un numero que se guarda en la variable cantEmpresas, la cual luego utilizo en un for, pero esta no esta llegando correctamente y no soy capaz de visualizar donde esta el problema, agradezco su ayuda

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MESES 12

void cargarNombreYApellido (char nombre[100]);
void crearContrasenia (char nombre[100], char password[200]);
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(int cantEmpresas);
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, int empresas[][MESES]);


//#############################################################
int main()
{


int cantEmpresas;
elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(cantEmpresas);

int empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]);

    return 0;
}
//##############################################################



int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(int cantEmpresas){
    printf("\n\n\nCon cuantas empresa deseas trabajar? (Menos de tres) \n");
    scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);
//agregar problema al añadir 3 empresas o mas
}
//En este for no llega el cantEmpresas, si funciona cuando introduzco otro numero
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, int empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]){
int i;

for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++){
        printf("f");
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Haz que la función `elegirCantidadDeEmpresas` retorne el número de empresas y por cierto, no uses [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) 
 (Variable-length-Arrays), sino, memoria dinámica con [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Comment: @MrDave1999 Porque no deveria usar VLAs?

Comment: @Pablochaches Los VLA se agregaron en el estándar C99, pero es opcional, por lo tanto, dependerá del compilador. Sí interesa escribir código que compile en cualquier lado, no se lo debería de usar. Otra razón sería que es propenso a que ocurra un desbordamiento de pila si se ingresa un tamaño muy alto.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Gracias

Comment: Hola, no entiendo en que momento yo utilice VLA, es algo que nunca me explicaron en la universidad, si no que solo me explicaron este metodo para hacerlo

Comment: @HatoriHanso Esto es un VLA: `int empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];` La primera longitud se obtiene en tiempo de ejecución.. La forma correcta de hacer esto es creando una matriz dinámica (ver este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376010/c%c3%b3mo-funcionan-realmente-los-arrays-bidimensionales-din%c3%a1micos-en-c/376118#376118)).

Comment: @HatoriHanso Lo usas en esta linea: `int empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];`. Ya que `cantEmpresas` no es cosntante

Comment: @MrDave1999 Wow. Comentamos sincronizados la respuesta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu problema radica en que pasas el parámetro por valor y no por puntero. Vamos a lo básico:

En c hay dos maneras de pasar parámetros a una función.  Por valor y por puntero. (Además en C++ podrías pasar el valor *por referencia*).

Cuándo pasas parámetros por valor, en realidad el programa hace, tras bambalinas, una *copia* de la variable, de tal manera que cualquier modificación que se le haga dentro de la rutina, no se verá reflejada en la variable con la que se hizo la llamada.

Cuando pasas un parámetro por puntero (o por referencia), en cambio, se pasa "la variable misma" —en realidad, su dirección de memoria— y se trabaja sobre ese mismo espacio de memoria de manera que cualquier cambio realizado dentro de la rutina se verá reflejado en la variable que se utilizó para llamarla.

En compiladores modernos, puedes utilizar el operador `&` en la declaración de la función, para pasar por referencia.

En otras palabras, para pasar el parámetro por referencia, en la declaración de la función, cambia a algo como:

```
void elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(int &cantEmpresas){
```

Y el resto del programa no sufriría cambio alguno.

En C estándar clásico, sin embargo, debes utilizar punteros, es decir, cambia la declaración y también la forma de utilizar el parámetro y de llamar a la función:

```
void elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(int *cantEmpresas){
  *cantEmpresas = 5
```

Y la llamada cambia a:

```
elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(&cantEmpresas);
```

Dicho esto, hay una inconsistencia importante en tu código: tu función, según su declaración, devuelve un entero (que podría ser la cantidad de empresas). Sugiero que hagas esto, o que cambies la declaración de tu función para que no devuelva nada (`void`):

Si te decides por lo primero, todo se simplifica, pues ya no hay parámetros:

```
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas() {
  return 5; 
}
```

Y la utilizas así:

```
cantEmpresas = elegirCantidadDeEmpresas();
```

Comment: *En c hay dos maneras de pasar parámetros a una función. Por valor y por referencia...* En C [no existe el concepto de pasar por referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353484/c%c3%b3mo-funcionan-los-punteros-por-referencia-pasados-como-par%c3%a1metro-de-funciones/353719#353719).

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, he cambiado la redacción para expresar los conceptos con mayor propiedad. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Si ya has creado una función que retorna un entero, es innecesario que le pases una variable como parámetro, aprovecha que la función ya te devuelve un valor para retornar la cantidad de empresas:

```
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas()
{
    int cantEmpresas;
    printf("\n\n\nCon cuantas empresa deseas trabajar? (Menos de tres) \n");
    scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);

    return cantEmpresas;
}
```

Y en tu main lo llamas así:

```
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas();

int main()
{
   // Elegir cantidad empresas.
   int cantEmpresas = elegirCantidadDeEmpresas();

   int empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
   cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]);

   return 0;
}
```