# ¿Se puede acceder a cualquier valor como si fuese un puntero?

Tags: c, punteros, memoria

En C existen dos operadores punteros: `&`, que devuelve la ubicación de memoria del dato junto al que se pone, y `*`, que devuelve un dato de esa dirección de memoria.

Entonces:

¿Se podría acceder a una dirección de memoria dada por el valor de una variable?

Ej:

```c
    int* a;
    a = 15;
    printf("%d", *a);
```

Aquí, si estoy en lo cierto, se imprimiría el valor de la ubicación de memoria **15**.

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La idea que tienes es en cierto modo correcta, pero faltan algunos detalles.

El compilador verifica que estés utilizando los tipos correctos en cada operación. Cuando usas el operador `*` delante de una variable, el compilador ha de verificar que esa variable es de tipo puntero. En este caso no lo es, por lo que te dará un error de compilación.

Sin embargo nada te impide declarar `a` como `int *` y darle el valor 15. En ese caso sí que tendrás un puntero que apunta a la dirección 15 y podrás escribir `*a` sin obtener errores de compilación. Es decir:

```
int *a;

a = 15;
printf("%d\n", *a);
```

No obstante esto es una mala idea y seguramente causará un error en tiempo de ejecución o algo peor. Te explico por qué.

Al hacer `a = 15` de momento no estás haciendo nada prohibido. Simplemente has almacenado el número 15 en la variable `a`. Ya que el valor de un puntero es en principio un número, no hay problema con esa asignación.

El problema viene cuando después intentas `*a`. Eso causará que la CPU intente acceder a la dirección de memoria 15. En cualquier sistema operativo hoy día la memoria está protegida para que un programa no pueda acceder a ninguna dirección que no le "pertenezca". Las direcciones que pertenecen al programa son aquellas en las que ha sido cargado, las de su zona de datos donde están sus variables globales, las de la pila donde están las variables locales, y parte del *heap* que le haya sido asignado a través de `malloc()`.

Muy probablemente la dirección 15 no estará en ninguno de los casos anteriores. Será una dirección que "no pertenece" a tu programa. El intento de acceso a una dirección no permitida es abortado inmediatamente. La propia CPU genera una excepción interna que causa la interrupción de tu proceso, haciendo que entre el sistema operativo a ver qué ha pasado. El sistema operativo típicamente terminará tu proceso y mostrará al usuario un error del estilo "Este programa ha hecho una operación ilegal", o bien "Segmentation fault".

Ahora bien, pudiera ser que por casualidad hubieras asignado a la variable `a` una dirección que sí "pertenezca" a tu programa. En ese caso el acceso a `*a` no produciría ninguna excepción y podrías ver el contenido de esa dirección de memoria.

Más peligroso es que intentes *cambiar* el contenido de esa dirección con algo como `*a = 0` (estaríamos tratando de meter un 0 en la dirección 15). Si la dirección estaba protegida (no "pertenecía" a tu programa) el proceso será terminado como cuando intentabas leer. Pero si la dirección "pertenecía" a tu programa, esa asignación tendría éxito, y habrías cambiado parte de la memoria de tu proceso. Las consecuencias de esto son imprevisibles, pues es posible que hayas modificado alguna instrucción de código máquina, o que hayas modificado el valor de alguna otra variable del programa, o la dirección de retorno de una función...

Es por esto que a un puntero no se le asigna nunca una dirección "directamente", sino de forma indirecta, usando la dirección de otra variable o el valor retornado por `malloc()`.

### Edición: *Warning* al compilar

El ejemplo que puse más arriba dará un *warning* (advertencia) al compilar. El mensaje concreto depende del compilador, pero la idea general es que `15` es un entero, y no un puntero y por tanto el compilador "no está cómodo" asignándoselo a `a`, que sí es un puntero. Pese a eso lo hará.

El problema es que, aunque conceptualmente un puntero no es más que un número, no es habitual asignarlos directamente como hace ese código, y el compilador está preparado para avisarte ante una asignación de este tipo, no vaya a ser que sea una confusión tuya y que estuvieras pretendiendo hacer otra cosa.

Para indicarle al compilador que sabes lo que estás haciendo (es decir, que lo estás haciendo así a propósito) y evitar de ese modo el aviso, puedes "forzarle" a que considere el 15 del tipo que a tí te interese, mediante lo que se denomina un *casting* que consiste en poner entre paréntesis delante del 15 el tipo que quieres que vea el compilador.

En este caso, para que el tipo coincida con el de la variable `a` (que es un puntero a `int`) deberíamos decirle que considere al 15 también como un puntero a `int`. La asignación con el *casting* que evita el *warning* sería por tanto:

```
a = (int *) 15;
```

Comment: Pero, a mi me ha dado error `a = 15`, `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`, no se muy bien por qué :(

Comment: No es un error, es un _warning_. Pese al aviso, te ha tenido que generar un ejecutable que funcionará según he descrito. De todas formas edito la respuesta para explicar por qué pasa esto.

Comment: Si, tienes, razón, me ha creado un `EXE`, pero nada más ejecutarlo me ha dejado de funcionar xD. Bueno, gracias.