# ¿Se puede crear un puntero dinámico?

Tags: c, punteros, memoria

Hoy me ha surgido una duda. Los punteros en C se declaran de la siguiente forma:

```
int a = 15;
int * ptr = NULL;
ptr = &a;
```

Aquí se crea una variable de tipo `int` (`a`) y luego se le asigna al puntero `ptr` su ubicación en la memoria.

Mi pregunta es ¿esta dirección de memoria se podría colocar de forma manual?

Ej:

```
int * ptr = NULL;
ptr = 2020;
```

Aquí, se le asignaría al puntero `ptr` la dirección de memoria `2020`; pero solo si es como yo creo que podría ser.

¿Alguien sabe si esto existe?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene respuesta aqui: --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/396100/7123

Comment: Por cierto que esto que intentas no sería un puntero "dinámico", sino más bien un puntero descontrolado :-) La forma correcta de reservar memoria dinámicamente es usar `malloc()`.